# Save transcript to file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

Is there a way to save a transcript of the entire shell interactions (inputs and outputs) to a file via the shell like illustrated in the below code?

```
Save = input(print("Do you wish to save your transcript (1 = yes, 2 = no) "))
if Save == int(1):
    *****trigger to save transcript to file******
```

Thanks for the help!
(I dont care what file type it is, as long as it is human readable (md, txt, ect))

Comment: Do you mean `script`? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/script-command-in-linux-with-examples/

Comment: no, I would like to do this via the user shell, so a user can do it without using commands